# Azure Virtual Machine acting as Server for Mobile Application

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, denial-of-service

I would like to know what can be done to prevent Denial of Service attack on the server for the mobile application hosted by a Virtual Machine on Azure. Is it possible to prevent DoS attacks ?

Comment: Short answer: Yes.

Comment: @HenkHolterman How can it be done ?

Answer (score 0):

There's a new, in preview, service in Azure called [Azure DDoS Protection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/ddos-protection-overview) that might be of interest for you.

It's a feature you enable at the network level in your VNet. If it's not available, at the time of writing, it most likely means the feature is not enabled in your subscription.

Also check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35317910/microsoft-azure-ddos-protection) for future reference on what the current state is in Azure.

Answer (score 0):

By default, you're protected by **Azure DDoS Protection Basic** so there's nothing to do and it's included in the service price.  The Standard version provides more features at a cost.

> **Azure DDoS Protection Basic**: Automatically enabled as part of the
> Azure platform, at no additional charge. Always-on traffic monitoring
> and real-time mitigation of common network-level attacks provides the
> same defenses utilized by Microsoft’s online services. The entire
> scale of Azure’s global network can be used to distribute and mitigate
> attack traffic across regions. Protection is provided for IPv4 and
> IPv6 Azure public IP addresses.
>
> **Azure DDoS Protection Standard**
> Provides additional mitigation capabilities tuned specifically to
> Azure Virtual Network resources. It is simple to enable, and requires
> no application changes. Protection policies are tuned through
> dedicated traffic monitoring and machine learning algorithms and
> applied to public IP addresses associated to resources deployed in
> virtual networks, such as Azure Load Balancer, Azure Application
> Gateway, and Azure Service Fabric instances. Real-time telemetry is
> available through Azure Monitor views during an attack and for
> history. Application layer protections can be added through
> Application Gateway Web Application Firewall. Protection is provided
> for IPv4 Azure public IP addresses.